# Perl regular expression with split function

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a function to parse the output of the command that is executed on a linux box. I want the function to parse the command output and return the output to the calling function.  I want to parse the output to get `0/9999 (0%)` and return 0 and 9999. (Note: these numbers are not static. It could be any number of digits. For example `4567/100000 (45%)`). The regex that I have used is incorrect, I guess. I'm getting the output as 0.

Command output:

```
Connecting to host 8.2.0.2, port 7775
[  4] local 9.1.1.2 port 37675 connected to 8.2.0.2 port 7775
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-2.40   sec  5.49 MBytes  19.2 Mbits/sec  10000
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-2.40   sec  5.49 MBytes  19.2 Mbits/sec  5.958 ms  0/9999 (0%)
[  4] Sent 9999 datagrams

iperf Done.
```

Function:

```perl
sub test_output {

    my ($self) = @_;
    my $packets = 0;

    $self->{output_obj}->_exec('enter the command here');

    my @output = $self->{output_obj}->out();

    foreach my $line (@output) {
        if ($line =~ /(\d+\/\d+\s.*)/) {

            packets = $1
        }
    }
    my @values = split('/', $packets);
    foreach my $val (@values) {
        return "$val\n";
    }
}
```

Function call:

```perl
$self->{'client'} = $self->{'exec_obj'}->test_output()
```

Expected return value from the function:

```
lost  : 0
total  : 9999
lost percentage: 0%
```

Comment: You look to have a couple of problems here. 1. The RE matching against `$line` is going to match "0/9999 (0%)", so when you split on '/' you'll get "0" and "9999 (0%)". 2. You put a return inside the foreach loop. You'll return the first value, in this case "0"...and that's it. Not sure what you're trying to return. If it's a list, why not just return @values?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers i want to return 0 ,9999 and 0% separately.

Comment: The only way I know to do that in Perl is by returning a list. You can't return from a function multiple times. What if you try this: `if ($line =~ /(\d+)\/(\d+)[^(]*\((\d+%)\)/) { return ($1, $2, $3);}`. I think that might get you what you want (note, I didn't test this, but I think it should be close to correct.)

Comment: foreach my $line ( @stdout ){

    if ($line =~ /(\d+)\/(\d+)[^(]*\((\d+%)\)/)){                      }
}

return ($1, $2, $3);

}

Comment: @MichaelAlbers this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub test_output {

    my $self = shift;

    $self->{output_obj}->_exec('enter the command here');

    my @output = $self->{output_obj}->out();

    foreach my $line (@output) {
        if ($line =~ m/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s\((\d+%)\)/) {
            my ($lost, $total, $percentage) = ($1, $2, $3);

            return ($lost, $total, $percentage);
        }
    }
}

my ($lost, $total, $percentage) = $self->{'exec_obj'}->test_output()
```